# How to extract parts of a list that have the same name?

Tags: r

I want to extract parts of a list that are also a list into a data frame, but the parts I want have the same name. Here's an example list:

```
study <- list(type='RCT', samplesize=10, centre=list(date='10/2/2015', type='A'), centre=list(date='20/3/2015', type='C'))
```

If I use:

```
sapply('centre', function(x) unname(unlist(study[names(study)==x])), simplify=FALSE)
```

Then it comes out as a vector:

```
$centre
[1] "10/2/2015" "A"         "20/3/2015" "C"
```

What I want is:

```
centre date      type
1      10/2/2015 A
2      20/3/2015 C
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first subset the list names with `'centre'`, convert it to dataframe and assign row index.

```
data <- data.frame(t(sapply(study[names(study) == 'centre'], unlist)), 
                   row.names = NULL)
data$centre <- 1:nrow(data)

data
#       date type centre
#1 10/2/2015    A      1
#2 20/3/2015    C      2
```

---

You can also get `data` as :

```
data <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, study[names(study) == 'centre'])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are open for a concise tidyverse/purrr solution, we can use `imap_dfr()`

```
study %>% purrr::imap_dfr(~if(.y == "centre") .x)
#   A tibble: 2 x 2
#   date      type 
# * <chr>     <chr>
# 1 10/2/2015 A    
# 2 20/3/2015 C
```